# starter kit for python programming in VS2017

Tags: python

How should I start Python programming with **VS2017**? I already have downloaded the components.

Maybe a link of an arti

Comment: please log the error you are getting while you run the project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project?view=vs-2019) documentation for Python Projects in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.

Comment: I can Run the python file in VS Code. I want to create project and run it in Visual Studio 2017